# Access to SQL with Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have upsized my Access table to SQL but Crystal Reports does not seem to have acccess to data in linked MS Access tables. Do i have to relink all reports to SQL directly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have linked your SQL just like your access was linked.
Do You have Technical support or programming in-house?

Comment: I have upsized my database from Access to SQL and now my whole application works well (no errors, data get saved, retrieved, etc.) The only thing is i do not understand is: What should i do, or even better, where should i start with crystal reports? Do i make new reports, link them to SQL or do i change my source code and link existing reports to SQL database.